# A comparison of the global optimal binwidth and local optimal binwidth of the histogram estimator

Tags: convergence, kernel-smoothing, histogram, density-estimation, nonparametric-regression

Suppose we have $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to be an i.i.d sample with unknown pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$, and define $\hat{f} (x)$ to be the histogram estimator. We also define its Mean Integrated Square Error as $MISE(\hat{f} ) = \int MSE (\hat{f} (x))dx$.

Given its global optimal binwidth

$$h^{\star}_{glob} (x) = {\bigg [}\frac{\int f(\xi_x ) dx}{2\int \gamma_x^2 dx } {\bigg ]}^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot n^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

and local optimal binwidth

$$h^{\star}_{local} (x) = {\bigg [}\frac{f(\xi_x )}{2 \gamma_x^2} {\bigg ]}^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot n^{-\frac{1}{3}} $$

how can we make a comparison between the two?

My intuition is that one of them converges faster than the other but I am unable to make any link of the integrals to convergence rate..

Some insights will be deeply appreciated!